# Why is solidity throwing "Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. ", when clearly the issue is elsewhere?

Tags: remix, contract-debugging, error, payable, solidity-0.5.x

I'm writing a contract on **Remix** that is able to deploy and track child contracts.

Here are the 2 contracts:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

**Contract Factory**

```
contract ContractFactory{
    ChildContract[] public createdContracts;
    ChildContract public activeChild;

    function createChild() public{
        ChildContract newChild = new ChildContract();
        createdContracts.push(newChild);
        // if (address(activeChild) != address(0)){
            activeChild.activate(false);
        // }
        activeChild = newChild;
    }
}
```

**Child Contract**

```
contract ChildContract{
    bool isActive;

    constructor() public{
        isActive = true;
    }

    function activate(bool status) public{
        isActive = status;
    }
}
```

I deployed the ContractFactory and it was successful. Then I tried calling the `createChild` function. Then I got the following error:

```
transact to ContractFactory.createChild errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

As evident from the code, if I un-comment the commented out `if condition` inside the `createChild` function, the function will run without issues. My question is - Why is solidity throwing this misleading error, as the issue was with an unset variable?

Comment: It's just a guess and usually a wrong one. It means "I have no idea where the problem is, but did you check this one thing?"

Comment: This is not Solidity error, but rather Remix one.  “Note” about payable constructor is misleading, because you don't call constructor and you don't send value.  Though, second part of the “Note”, that suggests using “Debug”, looks relevant.

Comment: "Solidity throwing" implies that it is a compilation error, which is obviously not the case here. The exception is thrown during runtime, by the web3 client.

Comment: And the exception is thrown obviously because you've masked the `if (address(activeChild) != address(0))` statement, hence the attempt to call `activeChild.activate` reverts the transaction. The note... well, it is just a note to keep you aware of the fact noted...

Answer (score 0):

`Solidity throwing` implies that it is a compilation error, which is obviously not the case here.

The exception is thrown during runtime, by the web3 client (Remix in your case) which submits the transaction.

It is thrown because you've masked the `if (address(activeChild) != address(0))` statement, hence the attempt to call `activeChild.activate` (when `activeChild` points to address 0) reverts the transaction.

This information is explicitly provided to you by Remix:

```
transact to ContractFactory.createChild errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
```

The note about the constructor... well, it is just a note to keep you aware of the fact noted...

Answer (score 0):

Commenting out the check is the cause of the failure.

`activeChild` doesn't become a valid instance until later.

`activeChild = newChild;`

But this line seems to be trying to deactivate a predecessor. How can that work if there is no predecessor?

`activeChild.activate(false)`

On the first run, there will be no previous `activeChild`, so it is important to check or it will surely run into trouble.

I would probably be more explicit about the comparison.

`if(address(activeChild) != address(0)) { // carry on and deactivate it`

As other commentators have mentioned, the possible cause of the runtime error is merely a guess and it is often misleading.

Hope it helps.